# When will it be possible to buy SharePoint 2010 licenses?

Tags: sharepoint, licensing

We're about to spend some money buying 2007 licenses, however over the next few years it's highly likely we'll upgrade to 2010. Is it possible to buy Sharepoint 2010 licenses now?

and would these licenses allow us to run our 2007 instances?

We will probably only upgrade once SP1 of 2010 is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the Microsoft SKU's are only available once the product is RTM'ed. You really only have a couple options:

1) Move forward with 2007 and buy 2010 licenses when you are ready to upgrade

2) Wait till later this year and buy 2010 licenses when they are released (you generally have downgrade rights to deploy 2007)

3) Purchase 2007 licenses now with Software Assurance

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint Server 2010 will be released June 2010. I don't think you can buy any licenses yet.